# How to calculate the max value of cantor pairing function given the min and max of the inputs?

Tags: cantor-set

For the cantor pairing function

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function

which takes 2 numbers and returns another number. If I know the min and max values of each of the 2 inputs, is there a way I can automatically know what the biggest value of the cantor pairing function for some input within the ranges?

Comment: The Pairing function is increasing in both variables (see the explicit formula given in the wiki article), so just plug in the upper bounds.

Comment: So you are saying, if I use the biggest value of both inputs, that is the biggest output?